# how to sort array of objects according to a value of a specific property

Tags: javascript, node.js

As shown in the code below, I have an array and i push object inside in a loop. what I am trying to do is, sort it according to the value of delay 
property. I used the following code:

```
delayOfFeatures.sort((a, b) => a.delay - b.delay);
```

but the array does not change

**code**:

```
delayOfFeatures.push({ progSpace: progSpace, feature: feature, delay: delay });
```

Comment: You are sorting `delayOfFeatures` and the array you are pushing the values is `delayOfFeat`

Comment: is delay a number? or a string with a number and some text?

Comment: Here is a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

sort returns the sorted array, so var result = delayOfFeatures.sort((a, b) => a.delay - b.delay); result will have the sorted version, no loop needed.

Comment: @user15741 - `.sort()` does return the array, but it also sorts the original in place so the array it is returning is the original array.  There is no reason for an assignment.

Comment: You will need to show us more of your code because there's no problem with `delayOfFeatures.sort((a, b) => a.delay - b.delay);`.  That will sort the array via a numeric `delay` property just fine.  So, not sure what your problem is.  The code you show does not indicate any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample, where you can sort your `features` array according to the `delay` property in ascending or descending order.

```js
class Feature {
  constructor(name, delay) {
    this._name = name;
    this._delay = delay;
  }
  
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  
  get delay() {
    return this._delay;
  }
}

const features = [
   new Feature('Feature A', 1000),
   new Feature('Feature C', 500),
   new Feature('Feature B', 50),
   new Feature('Feature D', 1),
   new Feature('Feature E', 750),
];

// Ascending by delay
features.sort((a, b) => a.delay - b.delay);
console.log(features);

// Descending by delay
features.sort((a, b) => b.delay - a.delay);
console.log(features);
```

Comment: How is your sorting any different than the `delayOfFeatures.sort((a, b) => a.delay - b.delay);` that the OP already has in their question?

Comment: I tried to **make clear** to the OP what should be done in order to get the results the OP wants. That's why I filled up and array with simple, but a clear list of classes with a string and a number within each of them. Then, sort them in that 2 simple ways.